# Handling output of FileSystemInfo array

Tags: xml, powershell

So I am using

```
$list = Get-ChildItem $path -filter *xml
```

on a given path to find all the xml files in it. That appears to generate an array of FileSystemInfo typed objects.

Is there a best way to enumerate the names in a way that’s formattable and straightforward? Things get wonky real fast when I start to use

```
$list | ft
```

And such on it – because I believe it’s handling them as objects. Which is expected. But not quite what I’m going for.

Do you have any high-level guidance on what I’m dealing with here and the best way in PS to go about chopping it up in an arbitrary way – ie human readable. Is a foreach() loop just the best idea? I feel it would work but isn’t ideal.

Comment: Example : `Get-ChildItem $path -filter *xml | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`. That will only display the value of the `Name` property for each file found. If you want the full path, try with `FullName`.

Comment: It really depends what you want to do with it. Many cmdlets match parameter by property name. So you dont need to use a loop structure per se on them at all. Do you have an example of what you want it to look like possibly?

Comment: Need to be careful as you will match folders that end in xml as well. `-file` would address that assuming you have v3 or higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really just sounds like you are asking for [`Select-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx) which:

> selects **specified** properties of an object or set of objects.

You mention that you are looking for a human readable method to enumerate names?

Like [sodawillow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532532/handling-output-of-filesysteminfo-array#comment56806476_34532532) says you can just extract that one property to get an array of names

In PowerShell V2. *Need to be careful as you will match folders that end in xml as well.*

```
Get-ChildItem $path -filter *xml | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

In PowerShell V3+

```
(Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *xml -File).Name
```

But that would only get you the strings. How are you looking to process them? A simple foreach would be the easiest well rounded approach.

```
(Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *xml -File).Name | ForEach-Object{"The file name is $_"}
```

However if you were doing something else like moving the file there are cmdlets that would process the output of `Get-ChildItem` directly without the need of explicit looping.

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *xml -File | Move-File -Destination "C:\temp"
```

That works because of matching parameters by property name which [Move-Item](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849852.aspx), and many other cmdlets, can do.

> -Path Specifies the path to the current location of the items. The default is the current directory. Wildcards are permitted.
>
> ```
> Aliases                        none 
> Required?                      true 
> Position?                      1 
> Default Value                  none 
> Accept Pipeline Input?         true (ByValue, ByPropertyName) 
> Accept Wildcard Characters?    false
> ```